# controller in sub-directory not accessible on hosting server in codeigniter application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing

I am finding it very hard to access controller/function in the sub-directory on hosting server but it works perfectly on localhost
here is my folder structure
abc.com
       httpdocs
            cms
           .htaccess
               application
                     controller
                           page  (its controller out of sub-direcory)
                           admin (its subdirectory)
                                user (controller in admin sub-direcory not accessible)
    if i access it via url : abc.com/gms/admin/user/test it gives me
    Not Found
    The requested document was not found on this server.
    the only accessible thing is
    abc.com/gms (it accesses the page/index controller/function) any other URL gives me not found error 
    code from .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /gms

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]



</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

code from routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

code from config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Please advice I really want things done as it more than 3 days I am unable to proceed on hosting server and yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

in your apache configuration. httpd.conf

check the root setting

AllowOveride all